# Using Quikrete gravel for landscape?

Tags: landscaping, gravel

I'm looking to add some gravel between my timber steps, similar to what is in the picture below.

**Does this gravel look similar to what I'd find in a bag of 3/4" gravel from Quikrete?**

I'm not sure if the Quikrete is consistently sized or if it's just a bunch of pieces and bits up to 3/4". If the Quikrete is more or less consistently sized, it would be ideal and allow me to bring a few bags home rather than needing to have a small amount delivered in bulk. Thank you!

[image: Timbers with gravel]

Answer (score 1):

The Quikcrete website only lists one gravel product, "all-purpose gravel" sized 3/8 in, not 3/4.

The [data sheet](https://www.quikrete.com/pdfs/data_sheet-quikrete%20sand%20&%20gravel%20products.pdf) says it conforms to ASTM 33, which implies that either 85% or 90% of the material will be between 3/8 and 3/16 in - it's not quite clear exactly which specification in ASTM 33 they are referring to.

The gravel in your picture looks bigger than 3/8in to me.

Comment: Thanks. The big box stores (Home Depot, Lowes) sell a 3/4" gravel from Quikrete. Not sure why it's not listed on the Quikrete website. I'm hoping someone that has used the product and is familiar with it can comment on what one typically finds in those bags and if it's actually viable for this application.